# Should np.load() be in with with open

Tags: python, numpy, with-statement

Traditionally in python one user `with` to open files such that the file automatically closes when you exit the inner scope.

```
with open('file.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

In the numpy [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) it shows both `np.load` and `with load`

```
with load('foo.npz') as data:
    a = data['a']

a = np.load('/tmp/123.npy')
```

It looks like the `with` method only works with .npz files. Does `a=np.load()` automatically close the data file just like when the `with` context is closed?

Comment: See the notes in the link you provided. Specifically "The underlying file descriptor is closed when exiting the ‘with’ block."

Comment: In the `npy` case there's nothing for you to close.  `a` is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using random files from my current work dir:

Using `with` with a `npz`:

```
In [51]: with np.load('f.npz') as f:print(f['b'])
['q' 'r' 's']
```

Using a 'plain' load with a `npy`:

```
In [55]: a = np.load('adict.npy',allow_pickle=True)
In [56]: a
Out[56]: 
array({'#Ineligiblevets': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), 'test': 'one'},
      dtype=object)
```

`a` is an array, so can't be "closed":

```
In [57]: a.close()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-57-3980b52f6377>", line 1, in <module>
    a.close()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'close'
```

It is possible to `open` the file before hand, and pass via `with`, but you have to get the modes right, so it really doesn't help (unless you are doing something special):

```
In [59]: with open('adict.npy', 'rb') as f:
    ...:     a = np.load(f, allow_pickle=True)
    ...: 
In [60]: a
Out[60]: 
array({'#Ineligiblevets': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), 'test': 'one'},
      dtype=object)
```

Trying to use a `npy` load in a `with` doesn't work because an `array` does not have required `enter/exit` methods:

```
In [61]: with np.load('adict.npy', allow_pickle=True) as data: a=data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-61-1025c4c8c4a8>", line 1, in <module>
    with np.load('adict.npy', allow_pickle=True) as data: a=data
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `a=np.load()` does not automatically closes the file. You can close it yourself by using `a.close()`. In fact, if you have .npz file saved with np.savez, then the load method will only fetch the archive info, but it will not load the entire file. Therefore, the file remains open.

You can use `with` context manager with both npz and npy by calling:

```
with np.load('foo.npz', allow_pickle=True) as data:
      a = data['a']
```

Same works with npy files.

Comment: Loading a `npz` is different from a `npy`.  `load(...npy)` returns the data, openning and closing the file itself.  You can't `close` the npy array.

Comment: @hpaulj that is correct. Nevertheless, I prefer to use `with np.load()...` for both types of files, so that I do not have to think about it

Comment: What's the `npy` version with `with`?

Comment: with np.load('foo.npy') as data:

Comment: But `data` is an array.  It doesn't have the required `enter/exit` methods to use in a `with`.  Try it yourself!